# django connect to mysql and mongodb

Tags: mysql, django, django-rest-framework, djongo

I have 2 databases mysql and mongo. On mysql people hold all data and on mongo just images. I have defined them like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '1*****',
        'PORT': '1*****',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': '*****',
            # 'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        },
        'mongodb':  {
            'ENGINE': 'djongo',
            'NAME': '*****',
            'USER': '*****',
            'PASSWORD': '*****',
            'HOST': '*****',
            'PORT': '*****',
            'TEST': {
                'NAME': '*****',
                # 'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            },
        }

    }
}
```

Now I want to run inspectdb on mongodb and I het this error

```
manage.py inspectdb --database mongodb
django.db.utils.ConnectionDoesNotExist: The connection mongodb doesn't exist
```

The host password port is ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote `mongodb` at the *same* level as `'TEST'`, etc. This thus means that you only defined *one* database, and that `mongodb` is a key of that dictionary.

You thus should specify the `mongodb` database at the *same* level like the `default` database:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '1*****',
        'PORT': '1*****',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': '*****',
            # 'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        }
    },
    'mongodb':  {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': '*****',
        'USER': '*****',
        'PASSWORD': '*****',
        'HOST': '*****',
        'PORT': '*****',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': '*****',
            # 'CHARSET': 'utf8',
        },
    }
}
```